# .Net C# WSDL simple use assistance

Tags: c#, asp.net, wsdl

I am OK with C# but was dropped a project when a dev we had quit. I have the WSDL Url and have added the service references to my VS2017 project etc but am having a difficult time getting some basic stuff working. Once I get one of the simple things worked out everything else will fall into place. I have used SOAPUI to send requests etc so I know the expected responses etc. I am trying to get a simple example to fill in the blanks. There is Zero info in the dev docs and most of this stuff is pretty outdated. I have worked with REST APIs etc but this is killing me.

The WSDL Url = https://uat-3pa.dmotorworks.com/pip-vehicle/services/VehicleInsertUpdate?wsdl

this is a test sandbox

I am trying to get the getVehicleIdRequest to return. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I created a project, right-clicked Dependencies > Manage Connected Services, and added a service reference to the WSDL URL. It created a client with all of the methods and models. That's as far as I got because the methods require an authentication token. Is that what you were looking for?

Comment: I have the authentication token portion worked out. It is the process of actually using the methods and classes and getting the response back. being as this is a test sandbox with no live data etc, I would not be uncomfortable DM'ing you the creds for this. Once it moves to production the urls all change along with the username and passwords etc.

Comment: If you do the steps I've described above it will do pretty much all the work for you. It creates a class - `VehicleSaveClient`, and that client has all of your methods. It also generates classes from the WSDL.

Comment: I got all that, thank you. I am a part time coder. I can usually get through things fairly well when the docs have a simple example of use. The docs here are devoid of anything like that and there is no dev community online or examples I can use to get over the initial understanding curve. What I would like is some help actually using this once to send and receive a response. I initialized the classes to populate a dealerId and Vin etc but need some assistance with a simple send and return here. One example and I should be good to go. I thank you for your assistance here.